# Setting an image in JavaFX. Exception Invalid URL

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I want to change the image in ImageView. I am getting the correct URL from the database but when I use it to set the image, it gives a error saying "Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c". What does this mean ? and how can i fix it. If I use relative path still not able to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/483eZ.png)

Comment: Do not use images for text information like code, logs and errors. Edit your question and paste the actual text.

Comment: What package is the Image class from?

Comment: is the URL something like `C:\Users\...` ? That definitively is not a valiD URL; more like a path - a valid URL would be something like  `file:/C:/Users/...` or `https://stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: (you can change the database entry, or use `Path.of(path).toUri().toURL()`, or `new File(path).toURL()` if a URL is *needed*)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other